# lme4 error message "Error in getOptfun(optimizer)"

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to figure out how to do a generalized mixed model using lme4.  I have been continually getting this error message when I attempt to run my model:

```
Error in getOptfun(optimizer) : couldn't find optimizer function bobyqa
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In get(optimizer) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(optimizer) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

I tried to work through [this demonstration](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf) to learn how to do the model , but I get the same error message when I get to this line from page 8:

```
politeness.model = lmer(frequency ~ attitude + (1|subject) + 
        (1|scenario), data=politeness)
```

I cannot seem to find anything about what this message means and I was wondering if anyone knows how to address it.

Comment: My guess is that this is a transient error. Try (1) restarting R (clean session); (2) reinstalling `lme4` and restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic code from the tutorial:

```
dURL <- "http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/politeness_data.csv"
politeness <- read.csv(dURL)
library("lme4")
politeness.model <- lmer(frequency ~ attitude + 
                         (1|subject) + (1|scenario), 
      data=politeness)
```

This works fine for me in the most recent version of `lme4`, but
I expect it should work with (a clean install of) just about any
version.

Comment: Thanks, restarting seemed to have worked.  Sorry to have bothered you with what was such an easy fix.